# oracle - maximum per group

Tags: sql, oracle

University Table - UniversityName, UniversityId

Lease Table - LeaseId, BookId, UniversityId, LeaseDate

Book Table - BookId, UniversityId, Category, PageCount.

For each university, I have to find category that had the most number of books leased.

So, something like

```
UniversityName Category #OfTimesLeased
```

I have been playing around with it with some success using `Dense_Rank` etc - but if there is a tie, only one of them shows up, while I want both of them to show up.

Current Query:

```
select b.UniversityId, MAX(tempTable.type) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY tempTable.counter DESC)
from book b 
join 
(select count(l.leaseid) AS counter, b.category, b.universityid
from lease l
join book b
on b.bookid =l.bookid AND b.universityid=r.universityid
 group by b.category, b.universityid) tempTable
 on counterTable.universityid= b.universityid
 group by b.universityid
```

^Unable to solve the tie issue and get the number of leases for the most leased book type.

Comment: post your current query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT UniversityName, Category, Count(*) NumOfTimesLeased 
FROM University u
INNER JOIN Book b on u.UniversityId = b.UniversityId
INNER JOIN Lease l on b.bookid = l.bookid and b.UniversityId = l.UniversityId
GROUP BY UniversityName, Category    
), 
CTE2 AS (
SELECT UniversityName, Category, NumOfTimesLeased,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UniversityName 
             ORDER BY NumOfTimesLeased DESC) Rnk
FROM CTE)

SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE Rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with the analytic functions:

```
select Univerity, Category, NumLeased
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by university order by Numleased desc) as seqnum
      from (select l.university, b.category, count(*) as NumLeased
            from lease l join
                 book b
                 on l.bookid = b.bookid
            group by l.university, b.category
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

I use the row_number() because you only want the one top value.  Rank and dense_rank are more useful when you are looking for values other than "1".

If you want the top values to show up when there is a tie, then use `dense_rank` instead of `row_number`.  The values will be on different rows.

Comment: i think he wants more than 1 values, from op's last statement - `but if there is a tie, only one of them shows up, while I want both of them to show up.`